# jQuery serializeArray() add another value on top for passing to Ajax

Tags: jquery, serializearray

I'm doing the following:

```
var data = $(form).serializeArray();
// Now I want to  add another value on this data
data.username = 'this is username';
```

I want to know how can I add another value after doing `serializeArray()`. I tried all the things I know, but nothing is getting it to work. any ideas pls.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

try

```
data[data.length] = { name: "username", value: "The Username" };
```

Comment: Is it possible to send an array? I have a property as follows `public HttpPostedFileBase[] Documents { get; set; }` trying to send data in loop

Comment: Question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73194619/how-can-i-add-formdata-with-html-beginform

Answer (score 60):

```
var data = $(form).serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'username', value: 'this is username'});
```

see also: [jQuery post() with serialize and extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627936/jquery-post-with-serialize-and-extra-data)

Answer (score 7):

```
var FormAttr = $('#form_id').serializeArray();

FormAttr.push({name: "Name_Of_Attribute", value:"Value_Of_Attributes"});
```

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party, but I personally prefer

```js
const data = $(form).serializeArray().concat({
    name: "username", value: "The Username"
});
```

Answer (score -5):

I think it's just

```
data['username'] = 'this is a username';
```