# add additional data to $form.serialize() ajax post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have the following snippet where I am serializing form data and posting it via ajax.  I have come across a situation where I need to add additional data.  In this case I need to add a comma separated array called 'selectedHours'.  Is this possible?

I am creating 'selectedHours' through as shown below where it creates an array of list items with the class 'hour-selected'.  There are no form values, inputs, etc used in this aspect.

```
var selectedHours = [];
$('.hour-selected').each(function(k,v) {
    selectedHours.push($(v).text());
});

$.ajax({ 
    type: 'post',
    url: '/process/somepage.php',
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function (response) {
... and so on...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'post',
    url: '/process/somepage.php',
    data: $form.serialize() + '&hours=' + JSON.stringify(selectedHours),
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function (response) {
... and so on...
```

data sended are just a URL encoded string. You can append other value with a simple concatenation.

Comment: I had no idea it was that simple... learned one more thing with ajax... thanks!  Is JSON.stringify necessary?  selectedHours already returns 1pm,4pm,11pm for example.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a better solution to this might be to use jQuery's `serializeArray`, as suggested [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6627996/5931472):

```
var data = $form.serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'hours', value: selectedHours});

$.post('/process/somepage.php', data).done(doSomething);
```

This solution might be preferable because it avoids manually constructing a serialized data string, instead opting to passing the data on for jQuery to deal with.