# How to add data to a form when submitting via a POST AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using jQuery's `$.ajax()` function to submit a form. I pass the form data like this:

```
data: form.serialize()
```

However, I would like to add additional data to the POST request.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627936/jquery-post-with-serialize-and-extra-data), the way to do this is to use `serializeArray()` on the form, then push data onto the resulting array of objects. The problem is that when I then try to serialize the resulting array, jQuery returns an error.

Here is an example:

```
<form id="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstName" value="John">
    <input type="hidden" name="lastName" value="Doe">
</form>
```

JS:

```
console.log($("#test").serialize()); // firstName=John&lastName=Doe 

var data = $("#test").serializeArray();
console.log(data); // [Object, Object]

data.push({name: 'middleName', value: 'Bob'});
console.log(data); // [Object, Object, Object]

console.log(data.serialize()); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqj4E/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to call `serialize` on it? Simply follow the example code in the linked answer. Use `data` in your AJAX call, it is ready. Like `data: data`.

Comment: Did you try to use data in your ajax call after `.push()`; you shouldn't try to serialize the array.

Comment: @kapa the examples I've found for `$.ajax()` show the data as being passed as `form.serialize()`, which puts the inputs into a string (like a GET request would). That's why I'm trying to call `serialize()` on the array, to convert it to a string.

Comment: You may also use JSON http://jsfiddle.net/hqj4E/1/

Comment: @Nate Just read the docs instead of following examples blindly. Or follow examples blindly, and simply copy it from the answer in the linked question. Both methods will work in this case :).

Comment: That last line line looks a bit weird to me. You are serializing `data` which is in `serializeArray` format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by kapa, jQuery permits you to pass the array you get from `serializeArray()` directly as a `data` parameter, so your code can be as simple as;

```
var data = $("#test").serializeArray();

data.push({name: 'middleName', value: 'Bob'});

jQuery.ajax({
    data: data,
    // Other params
});
```

---

However, to explain why your previous code wasn't working (and here starts my previous answer); `serializeArray()` literally returns an array. Array's don't have a `serialize()` method on them; which is why your code was failing.

instead of using `serialize()` on the array returned from `serializeArray()`, call [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param);

```
var data = $("#test").serializeArray();

data.push({name: 'middleName', value: 'Bob'});
console.log(jQuery.param(data));
```

`jQuery.param()` is specifically provided to convert the `{ name, value }` pairs generated by `serializeArray()` into a query string.

Comment: It is unnecessary AFAIK. jQuery will be able to work with `data` simply.

Comment: @kapa: Ahhh you're right. I didn't realise jQuery supported that. I'll update my answer!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `jQuery.param(...)`. I have to start using it.

Answer (score 1):

`serialize` is a jquery method used to serialize a form object.  Once you call `serialize`, you no longer have a jquery object, and thus you cannot serialize it.  You should be able to pass your JSON object to `$.ajax` by stringifying it with the JSON object:

```
$.ajax({
   data: JSON.stringify(data)
   //...
});
```

Comment: -1 Why would you transform it to JSON? What is a JSON object in your language? :)

Comment: This will not give you the same POST data as normal serialization.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, sometimes it is easier to simply add hidden input elements, before the serilazation.

```
$('<input type=hidden>').attr({name:'middleName',value:'bob'}).appendTo('form#test')
```

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer since it doesn't answer the question.