# JQuery $.post() issue, nothing is performed

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a small problem with my jQuery function, and below is the code:

```
function registerUser()
{
    var formData = $('#registerForm').serialize();
    var dataPost = $.post('classes/login.php', {type:'register', data: formData} ,function (data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

Then my login.php file looks like:

```
$type = $_POST['type'];
$email = $_POST['data']['0'];
$password = $_POST['data']['1'];

function register_user($email, $password)
{
 global $db;
//lets add some code to register user
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (email, password, role, banned) VALUES (:email, :password, 'level1', 'N')");
    $stmt->execute(array(':email'=> $email, ':password'=> $password));
    $rowCount  = $stmt->rowCount();
   if($rowCount > 0)
   {
    // Success
    //  set session data and etc.
    return "success";
   }
   else
   {
    //  Failed
    return "Error, please try again!";
   }
}
$result = register_user($email, $password);
```

When I executed it I did not get any errors or anything but a simple blank line that does not show any data and the data does not get inserted into the database?

Comment: instead of return success just say `echo "success";`

Comment: okay so now I get "error, please try again" when I enter blank data, but when I enter in data and submit it returns nothing. Even though I changed it all the echo instead of return.

Comment: what you get `var_dump($_POST['data']);` ?

Comment: this is what is returned with var_dump: LoginEmail=test&LoginPassword=test

Comment: That's the bug point. wait, I am preparing answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to post extra parameter with form serialization.

```
function registerUser()
{
    var formData = $('#registerForm').serializeArray();
    formData.push({name: 'type', value: 'register'});
    var dataPost = $.post('classes/login.php', formData ,function (data)
    {
        console.log(data);

    });
};
```

Now Server side update

```
$type = $_POST['type'];
$email = $_POST['LoginEmail'];
$password = $_POST['LoginPassword'];

function register_user($email, $password)
{
 global $db;
//lets add some code to register user
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (email, password, role, banned) VALUES (:email, :password, 'level1', 'N')");
    $stmt->execute(array(':email'=> $email, ':password'=> $password));
    $rowCount  = $stmt->rowCount();
   if($rowCount > 0)
   {
    // Success
    //  set session data and etc.
    return "success";
  }
  else
  {
//  Failed
    return "Error, please try again!";
  }
}
$result = register_user($email, $password);
```

Reference: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627936/jquery-post-with-serialize-and-extra-data)

Comment: nice catch with the string issue found in `var_dump($_POST['data']);`.

Comment: okay so it now has the correct strings and broken up format! But I still fail every time. Thinking it has something to do with my PDO statement now.

Comment: Have you still verified `var_dump($_POST['data']);` ?

Comment: yup! I verified and that problem is fixed! :D Just trying to figure out why it is always false;

Comment: `$isSuccess = $stmt->execute(array(':email'=> $email, ':password'=> $password)); var_dump($isSuccess);` check value is true or false.

Comment: The results are: bool(false)

Comment: Your statement did not executed with success. now do `var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());` after `execute`

Comment: fixed it! It gave an error about the table configuration and the input that was being sent! :) Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80919/discussion-between-jagad89-and-user1626342).

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling that function, it's just there.  You need to put

`register_user($email, $password);`

at the bottom of your .php page.

And even better: update your function to return true or false instead of "success" and "Error, please try again!".  And then you can have the following

```
if(register_user($email, $password)){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failure";
}
```

Comment: $result = register_user($email, $password); is what I have at the very bottom of the page

Comment: In the code you provided, check_login isn't a function.  It's helpful to include any relevant code to your question.

Comment: sorry I meant register_user() and I didn't mean to forget it.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I change my function to that! Now I get returned false no matter what. Something to do with my data according to jaga89

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3817220/3112492  You want to use parse_str on $_POST['data']