# jQuery AJAX request data field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using this piece of code to make an ajax call:

```
 $('#filter').submit(function(){
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(), // form data
        type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            filter.find('button').text('caricamento...'); // changing the button label
        },
        success:function(data){
            filter.find('button').text('Filtra'); // changing the button label back
            $('.load').html(data); // insert data
            $('.grve-iso-spinner').hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I need to add more variables to the 'data' attribute, something like:

```
data : {
        var1: 'value1',
        var2 : 'value2'
    }
```

How can I merge the two data elements?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data: filter.serialize() + '&key=' + value,
```

It will add `key: value` pair to form `serialize` data. As `serialize` data is in the form of key: value pair, you can add additional values by following the same pattern

Answer (score 0):

As jQuery [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function produces a text string in standard URL-encoded notation, you only have to concatenate the new values you want to add:

```
var data = filter.serialize();
data += "&var1=" + value1 + "&var2=" + value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: 
[jQuery post() with serialize and extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627936/jquery-post-with-serialize-and-extra-data)

It uses serializeArray and pushes the extra data to the array instead, you can then pass this array to the ajax call.

```
var data = $('#filter').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'wordlist', value: wordlist});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = $('#filter').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'var1', value: value1});
data.push({name: 'var2', value: value2});

$('#filter').submit(function(){
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:{ data : data }, // form data
        type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            filter.find('button').text('caricamento...'); // changing the button label
        },
        success:function(data){
            filter.find('button').text('Filtra'); // changing the button label back
            $('.load').html(data); // insert data
            $('.grve-iso-spinner').hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```