# jQuery serialize data: class incorporation

Tags: jquery

I should think my question is radically different from

[jQuery post() with serialize and extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627936/jquery-post-with-serialize-and-extra-data][1])

for it does not relate to *adding* data to the array output but to *extending the contents* of the array objects.

jQuery serializeArray produces an array like so:

```
[ Object { name="myElement",  value="any value"}, etc ]
```

Is there a way to *extend* the content of the object so that it includes for example:

```
[ Object { name="myElement",  value="any value", class="any classes"}, etc ]
```

This of course could save you a lot of time rather than 'manually' prepare an object by traversing all input elements and pass it to an XHR function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var arr = $('form').serializeArray();
var newArr = [];
$(arr).each(function(index, item){  
    var className = $('[name="'+item.name+'"]').attr('class');
    item["class"] = className ? className : "";
    newArr.push(item);
})
console.log(newArr);
```

Here `newArr` will have class also.

Comment: I have no time now to test and implement it but as soon as I am back to the grind I will — and certainly cast a favourable ballot: at first glance your solutions makes sense.

Comment: Upvoted. Very smart and efficient. Wish I had devised it for myself. Thank you.