# Adding form fields to another array

Tags: javascript

I am using a script that handles file uploads.

Part of the script passes information from several fields to a variable name like this:

```
var inputs = data.context.find(':input').not(':button');
```

Later in the script it is used like this:

```
data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
```

The issue I am having is that I added a couple of additional, general, fields to the beginning of the form that I want to use in the form handler as well.

The two fields I added are:

```
<input id="uploaderName" type="text" name="uploaderName" required value="">
<input id="uploaderEmail" type="text" name="uploaderEmail" required value="">
```

So when this is called:

```
data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
```

I need formData to include inputs.serializeArray(), uploaderName, and uploaderEmail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change the selector here: `data.context.find(':input').not(':button');` to something more specific or add a class to the two new inputs and change your selector to exclude them.

Comment: If these fields are in the form then, from what you've posted, they should already be being picked up by your selector.

Comment: data.context is specific info generated by the script. The two fields I want to add are not contained in data.context

Comment: @SherwinFlight take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726583/jquery-serializearray-add-another-value-on-top-for-passing-to-ajax

Comment: How would I use that to put those to the 'inputs' array?

Comment: (edited my previous comment)

Comment: @adaam, I found info on that page that solved my problem. Thanks.